# Does an assimp based importer already exist?

Tags: python, import

I'm looking for but for now I haven't found one, I'm thinking of writing one, some good reason not to do it?

[assimp](http://assimp.org/)

It already has a [python binding](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/tree/master/port/PyAssimp) even though I'm not sure the status for python3.

Comment: What's the advantage in comparison to alembic?

Comment: Hi @brockmann, I don't know alembic, I can't find a page with the list of features, what formats does it support? It seems to me oriented to formats for video productions, assimp is more a game-oriented library

Comment: Hi @Alex, Alembic has all features getting geometry and animation from one dcc package to another (open source as well), not sure about game dev though.